# Updating database in Transaction from List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, petapoco

I have a database table which has 2 columns and I have a List where T has 2 properties.

How can I create a transaction so that I can effectively say:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET ColumnA = List<T> 1st property 
WHERE ColumnB = List<T> 2nd Property
```

A transaction may not necessarily be needed if one update will get executed but if I have 100 items in my List what will be required to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute these update statements in a loop, looping over your list

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    using(var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("Transaction")) {
        foreach(var item in list) {
            using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
                command.Transaction = transaction;
                command.CommandText = // set the command text using item
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case

Comment: +1, but you can (and probably should) be adding the values using `command.Parameters.AddWithValue`.

Answer (score 6):

For those using PetaPoco, I believe this is the correct way to do it:

```
var db = new PetaPoco.Database("MyDB");

try
{
    db.BeginTransaction();
    foreach (var item in NewData)
    {
        db.Execute("UPDATE MyTable SET ColA= @0 WHERE ColB = @1",item.PropertyA, item.PropertyB);
    }
    db.CompleteTransaction();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    db.AbortTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless that is multiple updates (i.e. it is multiple executions of an update statement) you do not need a transaction.

Perhaps you should give more details on the code actually executing...

Comment: Good point, a transaction may not be required. However I still need to know how to write the SQL/C# to get this working